# Using Hibernate to 'order by' a column which having a expression(sum, max, ...)?

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-order-by

```
select CONTRACT_ID, sum(PO_SPEND)
from   V_CONTRACT_ANALYSIS_202
group by  CONTRACT_ID 
order by  sum(PO_SPEND) desc
```

Comment: Please state precisely your question, we would like to help you.

Comment: @Jimmy: You can edit your question to format the code properly (check preview) and to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jimmy: I've formatted the codes for you, but there's only the standard SQL query string. Will be helpful if you provide some mapping information you have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

From the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping)

> SQL functions and aggregate functions
>   are allowed in the having  and order
>   by clauses if they are supported by
>   the underlying database (i.e., not in
>   MySQL).

It looks like you are using native SQL and not HQL however, but regardless of that you will need to check the database vendor docs to see if the DB supports ordering by an aggregated column. It *looks* correct though.

Comment: Oracle, Informix, MySQL, DB2, and SQL Server all allow it, at least in recent versions.